# Xpath with Ancestor with multiple tag names

Tags: xpath

I want generic xpath to get a button to add an item to the shopping bag depending on the product name.
So far this is quite easy, I get the element with the product name, go bag to the root of the container and then look for the button:

```
//*[contains(text(),'productname')]//ancestor::article//div[contains(@id,'AddToBagButton')]
```

But now things became more difficult since there are several layouts for the same container which do have different tags for the root element. In looking for how to express this I came up with this solution:

```
//*[contains(text(),'productname')]//ancestor::*[local-name()='article' or local-name='product']//div[contains(@id,'AddToBagButton')]
```

But unfortunately, this works only for the first local-name()='article' and not for the second local-name='product'.

Is there any way to cover both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the mutual parent node based on known child (productName) and then to find another child inside it (AddToBagButton) as following:

```xml
//*[local-name()='article' or local-name='product'][.//*[contains(text(),'productname')]]//div[contains(@id,'AddToBagButton')]
```

Also, since the `productName` is text content, we can reduce the above expression to the as following:

```xml
//*[local-name()='article' or local-name='product'][contains(.,'productname')]//div[contains(@id,'AddToBagButton')]
```

Comment: sorry, that does not work, it finds all products

Comment: I see. What about the updated answer?

Comment: sorry, both return no result, but I try to work with your idea

Comment: In case there are more nodes with `article` or `product` tag name so as it includes several products in it - we have a problem. So, the parent element should be defined to include only single product block in it.

Comment: I guess that was my mistake, I forgot the brackets for local-name for the second expression, when I add them to your solution, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! You are more than welcome!